# Extract nested column names from Spark DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I would like transform a Spark DataFrame containing nested columns into a new dataframe, where each row contains

- the path within the column in the original DataFrame. This path should be also extracted from json, if the value is given by json-string
- value in that column converted to string
- a given column from the original DataFrame

The problem can be demonstrated on the following example:

```
import json
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StringType, IntegerType, StructType, StructField


schema = StructType([
                 StructField("id", IntegerType(), True),
                 StructField("parsed_info", 
                      StructType([
                          StructField('shapes', ArrayType( StructType([
                                 StructField("name", StringType(), True),
                                 StructField("value", IntegerType(), True)
                              ])), True),
                          StructField("event", StringType(), True),                           
                      ]), True),
                 StructField("raw", StringType(), True),
    ])

data = [
    (0, ([('shape1', 3), ('shape3', 1), ('shape4', 0)], 'e10'), json.dumps({'info':{'shapes':[{'spec_name':'xxx', 'val':2}, {'spec_name2':'yyy', 'val':3}]}})),
    (1, ([('shape5', 0), ('shape0', 2)], 'e11'), 'some text'),
    (2, ([], 'e20'), 'noisy text hiding the json structure ' + json.dumps({'additional info':{'dark':3}}))
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)

df.printSchema()

df.show(truncate=False)
```

yielding

```
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- parsed_info: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- shapes: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- value: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- event: string (nullable = true)
 |-- raw: string (nullable = true)


+---+----------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id |parsed_info                                   |raw                                                                                    |
+---+----------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|0  |{[{shape1, 3}, {shape3, 1}, {shape4, 0}], e10}|{"info": {"shapes": [{"spec_name": "xxx", "val": 2}, {"spec_name2": "yyy", "val": 3}]}}|
|1  |{[{shape5, 0}, {shape0, 2}], e11}             |some text                                                                              |
|2  |{[], e20}                                     |noisy text hiding the json structure {"additional info": {"dark": 3}}                  |
+---+----------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

where the desired output is:

```
+---+----------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id |column_name                       |value                                                                |
+---+----------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|0  |id                                |0                                                                    |
|0  |parsed_info.shapes.element0.name  |shape1                                                               |
|0  |parsed_info.shapes.element0.value |3                                                                    |
|0  |parsed_info.shapes.element1.name  |shape3                                                               |
|0  |parsed_info.shapes.element1.value |1                                                                    |
|0  |parsed_info.shapes.element2.name  |shape4                                                               |
|0  |parsed_info.shapes.element2.value |0                                                                    |
|0  |parsed_info.event                 |e10                                                                  |
|0  |raw.info.shapes.element0.spec_name|xxx                                                                  |
|0  |raw.info.shapes.element0.val      |2                                                                    |
|0  |raw.info.shapes.element1.spec_name|yyy                                                                  |
|0  |raw.info.shapes.element1.val      |3                                                                    |
|1  |id                                |1                                                                    |
|1  |parsed_info.shapes.element0.name  |shape5                                                               |
|1  |parsed_info.shapes.element0.value |0                                                                    |
|1  |parsed_info.shapes.element1.name  |shape0                                                               |
|1  |parsed_info.shapes.element1.value |2                                                                    |
|1  |parsed_info.event                 |e11                                                                  |
|1  |raw                               |some text                                                            |
|2  |id                                |2                                                                    |
|2  |parsed_info.event                 |e20                                                                  |
|2  |raw                               |noisy text hiding the json structure {"additional info": {"dark": 3}}|
+---+----------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I cannot imagine how the desired output is going be used. Do you mind sharing how you're planning to use the requested output, so maybe I can help with that?